# How to merge with datetime.datetime(Object) from CSV file with timestamp(datetime64[ns]) from t.series?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge

I am relatively new to python and am getting below error when I try to merge datetime.datetime(Object) from CSV file with timestamp(datetime64[ns]) from t.series. How can I change timestamp(datetime64[ns]) to datetime.datetime?(I have other datetime.datetime(object) to add later so I prefer to change timestamp(datetime64[ns]) to datetime.datetime(object))

BaseDate is date from my CSV files. is_EOM_QOM came from computation from t.series.
[image]
[image]

'''BaseDate.merge(is_EOM_QOM,left_on='Date',right_on='Date', how='left')'''

ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and datetime64[ns] columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: please provide your data/code as text and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

In order to merge on field/fields, the dtypes of merge fields should be same. Try converting the dtype first and then use merge. Converting both to str in the below example.

```
BaseDate['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(BaseDate['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
is_EOM_QOM['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(is_EOM_QOM['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

BaseDate.merge(is_EOM_QOM,left_on='Date',right_on='Date', how='left')
```

If you want DateTime format for both the df try

```
BaseDate['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(BaseDate['Date'])
is_EOM_QOM['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(is_EOM_QOM['Date'])
BaseDate.merge(is_EOM_QOM,left_on='Date',right_on='Date', how='left')
```

Comment: Works nice. Thanks

Comment: Happy to hear that. if the solution helps you make sure you accept my answer by clicking the right mark. and upvote by clicking the triangle button which is facing upwards

Comment: Then now I have str format for my dates. How can I go back to datetime format from here? Since I have rest of dates comes from excel file to compare.

Comment: If I follow your second suggestion, what I get is Timestamp('2021-09-10 00:00:00') on BaseDate.iloc[0,0]. What I need to get is datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 10, 0, 0) on BaseDate.iloc[0,0]. This is the format I need due to rest of my data.

Comment: I edited my question(Title and body) to further clarify the object and timestamp that I have.